hooks.server and page.server authentication infinite loop
I am facing a problem with an infinite loop in my authentication process. I have a separate login system from my main page, which redirects to the /auth/callback path sending a token via URL parameters when the user logs in successfully. In this callback path, I have a +page.server.js file that receives the token and performs a validation via a request to an internal API. If the validation is successful, the session is stored in a cookie and the user is redirected to the home page (/).
On the other hand, in my hooks.server.js, the existence of this cookie is validated and, if it does not exist, the user is redirected to the login page. However, when I try to access my page, it redirects me to the login. When I successfully log in and return to the /auth/callback path, an infinite loop occurs, repeatedly redirecting me to login and back to callback without stopping. Interestingly, when I directly access my home page via the URL, the loop does not occur.
Based on the logs I've reviewed, it appears that the +page.server.js code is executing twice, while the hooks.server.js is executing once. Even though the cookie is copied correctly, the loop never stops, I don't know why this is happening or if I'm missing some settings.
Execution logs
cookie saved
redirecting to login
cookie saved
cookie saved
redirecting to login
cookie saved
cookie saved
redirecting to login

hooks.server.js
import { LOGIN_URL } from '$env/static/private';
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import cookie from 'cookie';

export const handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    const requestedPath = event.url.pathname;
    const host = event.url.host;
    const publicPaths = ['/auth/callback', '/auth/logout'];

    if (publicPaths.includes(requestedPath)) {
        return resolve(event);
    }

    const cookies = cookie.parse(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || '');
    const email = cookies.email;

    if (!email) {
        console.log("redirecting to login");
        throw redirect(303, `${LOGIN_URL}?srv=${host}/auth/callback`);
    }

    return await resolve(event);
};

+page.server.js
import { validateToken } from '../../../lib/auth';
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { LOGIN_URL } from '$env/static/private';

export const load = async ({ url, cookies }) => {

    const token = url.searchParams.get('apiToken');

    if (token) {

        const { success, data, error } = await validateToken(token);

        if (!success) {
            throw redirect(303, `${LOGIN_URL}/error?type=AuthError`);
        }

        const email = data.data.email;

        cookies.set('email', email, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            sameSite: 'strict',
            maxAge: 86400 * 1,
            path: '/'
        });

        console.log("cookie saved");

        throw redirect(303, '/');

    } else {
        throw redirect(303, `${LOGIN_URL}/error?type=AuthError`);
    }
};

I hope that when I receive my token in the path /auth/callback the session starts correctly and does not remain in an infinite loop of redirections.

Cannot reproduce this using a simplified setup. Also, in the handle hook event.cookies gives access to parsed cookies, there should be no need for a separate parsing library (docs for RequestEvent). Would recommend stepping through the code with a debugger to see all the values/cookies/URLs being received.

yes, I used the library just to try it, but finally the problem was due to the “sameSite: ‘strict’”, the domain of my external login is not the same of my site, so the cookie was not accessible because the requests to my callback came from an external domain and the redirection was to an internal domain, so the cookie did not exist, this was fixed using the rule “sameSite: ‘lax’”

Please post this as a proper answer and accept it.

finally the problem was due to the “sameSite: ‘strict’”, the domain of my external login is not the same of my site, so the cookie was not accessible because the requests to my callback came from an external domain and the redirection was to an internal domain, so the cookie did not exist, this was fixed using the rule “sameSite: ‘lax’”
